# Svelte/SvelteKit: Persisting authentication state with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to build a Svelte/SvelteKit web app that requires authentication. For this I'm using Firebase Authentication.

I can successfully create a new user and sign into the web app, but I cannot find a way to persist the authenticated state.

I have my `firebase.server.ts` file in `src/lib/server`:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const storage = getStorage(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)
const firestore = getFirestore(app)

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log('Auth state changed to true')
        authUser.set({
            isLoggedIn: true,
            user: user
        })
    } else {
        console.log('Auth state changed to false')
        authUser.set({
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: undefined
        })
    }
})

export { storage, auth, firestore }
```

I set the authenticated state in a `writable` called `authUser`.
The `authUser` is placed under `src/stores/` and looks like this:

```js
import type { User } from 'firebase/auth'
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

interface AuthUser {
    isLoggedIn: boolean
    user: User | undefined
}

let authUser = writable<AuthUser | undefined>(undefined)

export { authUser }
export type { AuthUser }
```

And in my `+layout.svelte` in `src/routes/` I have this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms'
    import { authUser } from '$lib/stores/authStore'
    import '../app.css'
</script>

<div class="px-40">
    <header class="py-4 space-x-8 w-full bg-red-400">
        <a href="/" class="font-semibold hover:underline">Home</a>
        <a href="/signup" class="font-semibold hover:underline">Sign up</a>
        <a href="/login" class="font-semibold hover:underline">Login</a>
        <p class="flex self-start">You are logged {$authUser?.isLoggedIn === true ? 'in' : 'out'}</p>
        <p>{$authUser?.isLoggedIn}</p>
        <form method="POST" use:enhance>
            <button type="submit" formaction="./?/logOut">Log out</button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main class="py-20">
        <slot />
    </main>
</div>
```

I expected that whenever I would log in, that `onAuthStateChanged` would trigger and a new state would be set on `authUser`, and it actually works. My `consol.log()`s confirms that.

But whenever I load the page I can see the text i expect to see, i.e. "You are logged **in**" for 1 millisecond before it changes to "You are logged **out**"

So what is the issue here? Why does the state change?

Answer (score 0):

Currently going through a similar problem I think it might have to do with your firebase being initialized on the server rather than the client. change your "firebase.server.ts" to "firebase.client.ts"